# For Web App is there a better way to pull an image from the camera?

Tags: javascript, html, video, stream, camera

I want to pull images from the camera, change/filter them with custom code, and display them in the browser in real time.  I'd like to know the best way to retrieve the image from the camera stream so I can process them.  Right now, I've taken sample code and cobbled something together that will take an image and displays it when I click a button.  I'm sure I can modify this to update the image more real-time.  But it seems very inefficient.  Here is what I'm doing

1. I use the video tag to create a place to draw the video.  I set the display style to none so it doesn't actually display on the screen
2. I use a canvas to copy the image out of the video on demand.  Again, I set the display to none because I don't actually want to see the image
3. When the button is clicked, I copy the image from the canvas and create an image URL containing the bytes of the image.  I display this image.

Here is the code

```
<html lang=”en”>

<body>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <main id="camera">

        <!-- Camera view -->
        <video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline style="display: none;"></video>

        <!-- Camera sensor -->
        <canvas id="camera--sensor" style="display: none;"></canvas>

        <!-- Camera output -->
        <img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">

        <!-- Camera trigger -->
        <button id="camera--trigger">Take a picture</button>

        <!-- Reference to your JavaScript file -->
        <script>
            // Define constants
            const cameraView = document.querySelector("#camera--view"),
                cameraOutput = document.querySelector("#camera--output"),
                cameraSensor = document.querySelector("#camera--sensor"),
                cameraTrigger = document.querySelector("#camera--trigger")

            // Access the device camera and stream to cameraView
            function cameraStart() {
                if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                        .then(function (stream) {
                            cameraView.srcObject = stream;
                        })
                        .catch(function (err0r) {
                            console.log("Something went wrong!");
                        });
                }

            }

            // Take a picture when cameraTrigger is tapped
            cameraTrigger.onclick = function () {
                cameraSensor.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
                cameraSensor.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
                cameraSensor.getContext("2d").drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);
                cameraOutput.src = cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/webp");
                cameraOutput.classList.add("taken");
            };
            // Start the video stream when the window loads
            window.addEventListener("load", cameraStart, false);            
        </script>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

It seems like I should be able to get the video stream, pull out the image directly at some interval or when the button is clicked, display that image.  At this point, I could write the code to modify the image before displaying it.

Any ideas?